How to do Linear Algebra Done Right Exercise 7.D 20
Suppose $S, T \in L（V）$. Let $s$ denote the largest singular value of $S$. Let $t$ denote the largest singular value of $T$, and let $r$ denote the largest singular value of $S+T$. Prove that $r \leq s+t$

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

I think this should work:
Proof.
The singular value $r$ of $(S+T)$ is also an eigenvalue of $E \triangleq \sqrt{(S+T)(S+T)^*}$ such that $Ek = rk$ for an eigenvector $k \in V$. We can compute that
$$ r ||k|| = ||rk|| = ||E k|| = ||(S+T)k|| = ||Sk + Tk|| \leq ||Sk|| + ||Tk|| \leq s||k|| + t||k||,$$ per linearity and the triangle inequality for $||\cdot||$. Hence, $r \leq s + t$.
